# Excel vlookup of untrimmed cell

Tags: excel, vlookup

I want to use `vlookup` but the column in the table that is to be searched has occasional entries with a trailing space. But `vlookup` cannot find these because of the trailing space.

```
vlookup('Smith',tablename, columnnumber,TRUE) cannot find 'Smith '.
```

The table is from an external database that I cannot edit. Setting the third parameter of vlookup to `FALSE` does not work either, although you would think that `Smith` is the next closest thing to `Smith`.

Comment: Don't adjust your methods; fix your data instead. A quick Text-to-Columns, Fixed Width, Finish will get rid of trailing spaces from an entire column.

Comment: That would certainly be best but, as I wrote, I do not have access to the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot wildcard your [VLOOKUP function's](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) *lookup_value* without risking a false positiove on *Smithers* when you are searching for *Smith*. However, the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) can pass control to an alternate VLOOKUP that appends a single space to the *lookup_value*.

```
=IFERROR(vlookup("Smith", tablename, columnnumber, FALSE), IFERROR(vlookup("Smith"&CHAR(32), tablename, columnnumber, FALSE), ""))
```

If *Smith* cannot be found then append a space character and try again. If it still fails, give up and pass back a zero-length string.

Answer (score 1):

How about wrapping the tablename with the trim function. Be sure and enter the formula with **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**:

```
=vlookup('Smith',Trim(tablename), columnnumber,False)
```

Comment: That does work, but I do not know how to copy this down a column.

Comment: Because it's an array, when pasting the formula you can't include the cell you copied from. For example, if you copy the formula from cell A2, when you paste you HAVE to paste to the range A3:A1000 or however far down it is. If however you include the cell you copy from and paste to the range A2:A1000, a message box will pop-up saying "You cannot change part of an aray".